# Delete folders that match name in different path

Tags: uninstall, directory

I have 2 folders in this situation, `/ParentFolder/FolderName/Files.mp4` and `/Mount/FolderName/Files.mp4`.

In essence anything in `/ParentFolder` needs to replace any folders with the same name in `/mount`. I have to use ACDCLI for the actual copy so I need to remove these first by calling any folder name from `/ParentFolder/*` and `rm -rf /mount/"FolderName"`

If it was one folder easy, but I'm not sure how to say, get all the folder names from X, and delete if they exist in Y.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash script should do what you describe. You may want to put an `echo` in front of the `rm` the first time you run it, just to make sure that it's going to do what you expect.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if test -d "$1"
then
    from="$1"
else
    echo "could not find source directory \`$1'" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if test -d "$2"
then
    to="$2"
else
    echo "could not find destination directory \`$2'" >&2
    exit 1
fi

for fromdir in "${from}"/*/
do
    todir="${to}${fromdir#"${from}"}"
    if test -d "${todir}"
    then
        rm -rf "${todir}"
    fi
done
```

Name the script something appropriate like `acd_prep` and use `chmod +x acd_prep` to make it executable. For the example folders in the question, you would then run the script as `acd_prep /ParentFolder /Mount`.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid, but where to I define the folder paths? Do I have to change each instance of $1 and $2 to my folder paths, or can I define them at the top of the file?

Such as $1=/Test/Test1, $2=/Test/Test2?

Thanks

Comment: this is a bash script, when you run a bash script you can add arguments.
'sh mybashscript.sh firstpath secondpath'
 $1 will become firstpath

Comment: As @FrankSchrijver pointed out, you would provide the source and destination directories as command-line arguments to the script. I've updated my answer with a usage example.